# onClick function style different then body

Tags: html, function, onclick

So im using the onclick function to assign a background color to classes (im not looking for alternatives for this i just need this to work). The function that gives the color to the body in this case is below.

```
function myFunction() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00';
}
```

This code works and styles the body with a background color. Now i was wondering if it was possible to use the onclick method to style a specific element on your page. So for example style the background color of a list item. I've tried:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.li.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00';
}
```

Comment: Yes... you have to use element selectors (`getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a couple different ways if you were to use jquery.

But if you're just using straight javascript the easiest way is to pass the object to the function like the following:

Have an html element like your example an li.

```
<li onclick="javascript:setColor(this);" />
```

Then have your javascript function like this:

```
function setColor(obj) {
     obj.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
}
```

As a preference I would want to pass the color code as a parameter as well but that's up to you.

Here's a jsfiddle with the color as a parameter:

http://jsfiddle.net/9yey1mhs/

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Now i notice the first item. Is it also possible to style another item while clicking the first item. In your example. Clicking the red line and then the blue line changes color.